# returning a user back to a previous line

Tags: python

I am trying to make the code return a user to a previous line of code based on an input they give.  If they answer "no" or "not really", etc. when I ask them if they understand the rules, I want them to return to the previous lines of code and read it all again.

```
print("Ok, the rules of this 'game' are very simple; You are kind of doing a virtual house tour.")
print("You will be inspecting the house for its condition and to see if it is 'sellable'.")
print("You will be going from room to room and checking it out based on the room description I give.")
print("You will be giving each room a number value of 0,1,2, or 3.  A 0 takes away from the value of the house.")
print("A 1 doesn't change the value of the house.  A 2 or a 3 increase the value of the house.")
print("If at any point in the tour you think the house is not 'sellable', you just have to say so and the game ends.")
print("Your progress in the house will be tracked at all times.")
ans2=input("Understand? Are you ready?")
if ans2.lower() in Accept_ans:
    print ("Ok, great!  Lets begin the tour.")
else:
    print("ok, read the instructions again")
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: It was solved already.  I was trying to make the script return back to the instructions if they answered no or something

Comment: if it's solved, can you please add your solution as a self-answer?

Comment: just did it, posted now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `while` loop to return to the starting point if the answer is not as expected.

```
ok = 0
while not ok:
    print("Ok, the rules of this 'game' are very simple; You are kind of doing a virtual house tour.")
    print("You will be inspecting the house for its condition and to see if it is 'sellable'.")
    print("You will be going from room to room and checking it out based on the room description I give.")
    print("You will be giving each room a number value of 0,1,2, or 3.  A 0 takes away from the value of the house.")
    print("A 1 doesn't change the value of the house.  A 2 or a 3 increase the value of the house.")
    print("If at any point in the tour you think the house is not 'sellable', you just have to say so and the game ends.")
    print("Your progress in the house will be tracked at all times.")
    ans2=input("Understand? Are you ready?")
    if ans2.lower() in Accept_ans:
        print ("Ok, great!  Lets begin the tour.")
        ok = 1
    else:
        print("ok, read the instructions again")
```